# Do the random vampire attacks end when you finish the main Dawnguard quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Do the random vampire attacks end when you finish the main Dawnguard quest on the Vampire Hunters (Dawnguard) side?

Comment: On the flip-side, do the random Dawnguard attacks end after finishing the Vampire side?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**, the attacks do end after finishing the main quest.

Tangentially, the attacks will *begin* as soon as you install Dawnguard, not after beginning Dawnguard-related quests. Some consider this a misfeature enough that a mod was quickly created to delay the attacks until the start of the main Dawnguard quest ([Dawnguard - No Vamp Attacks - WIP by IsharaMeradin](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/27530), no longer available, [Wayback Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130127224607/http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/27530)). It’s that bad.

More recent mods to solve this problem are:

- [Timing is Everything - Quest Delay and Timing Control](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/38151/?), a general-purpose quest delayer/control that includes Dawnguard
- [Dawnguard no Vampire Attacks SSE](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/2957)
- [Dawnguard Away - No Random Vampire Attacks in Towns - Delay Main Quest](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/94161)

… and so on. Basically, just search your favourite mod repository for `dawnguard attack` or `quest delay` and you’ll come up with a bunch of mods, if you’re interested in delaying or disabling the vampire attacks.

Comment: That link is now dead.  However, *if* you are trying to prevent random NPCs from dying in vampire attacks, [Protect your People](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/84394) is a much more thorough solution which does not require disabling the attacks at all.  (This is obviously useless if you "just don't like the vampires showing up.")